# Is there a way to Modify Recovery Menu Options?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, clockworkmod-recovery, aosp

Hi guys I am setting up an android system for a company, one of the requirements is that "employees can't factory reset/ wipe out data of a device". I have already done the proper implementations on the OS itself. however I was looking throught the recovery.img and boot.img files to see if I could modify any xml file or anything to hide or set password auth for the factory reset and wipe options from the recovery. I know a guy with knowledge would be able to activate it back, however the average employee barely knows what recovery is, so it's really unlikely.

It does not matter what type of recovery is needed to achieve this whether its an stock recovery or a twrp or cwm one. any ideas?

Comment: for custom recovery you probably have to unlock bootloader - which will open a backdoor for boot/flash/format/erase partitions from fastboot. better stay at stock recovery, enable FRP, enable cloud

Comment: it's possible to place a file in /cache partition which does factory reset, maybe you can place a command `--just_exit` which may disable recovery completely https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bootable/recovery/+/master/recovery.cpp

Comment: Oh thanks, Ok so, as I can tell, each function requested by the user such a "factory reset" creates a file with a command on the cache/recovery/command folder, however how should I store the file there as a just_exit entry? what file extension does it have? are those commands in a c# stuff as well?

Comment: so by removing the recovery partition the user won't be able to even access the menu right?

Comment: You can flash `boot.img` to `recovery` partition so that device always boots to normal OS. But all that it takes to boot into recovery mode is `fastboot boot recovery.img` if the user knows even the basics. An advanced way could be to modify bootloader so that it never boots from `recovery` partition. But it requires hacking closed-source bootloader binary and is very device-specific. Another idea is to define an `init` service which creates `/cache/recovery/command` file (as @alecxs mentioned) on every boot/shutdown. But I never tried this and it's also not hard to bypass with some knowledge.

Comment: flashing boot into recovery is worth a try, maybe there is a little chance the bootchain will detect it as (signed) stock image and allows to continue booting with (re-)locked bootloader