# How can I disable recovery mode?

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset

Is there a way to disable recovery mode so it won't be possible to factory reset your phone?

Basically what I am trying to do, is that it should be impossible to factory reset the phone as there is no recovery partition.

(Example format the recovery partition, or hide the option of factory reset on the recovery menu, build a custom recovery etc.)

P.S.. I was thinking of maybe removing a system app (example package installer) and making it a user app, and therefore when you factory reset the phone it won't start cause the system app is missing, but when I tried that, the phone wouldn't start even without resetting it, as the system needs the system app to start, ( I thought that maybe even though I removed the app from being a system app, the phone would still start as it's still there as a user app, and only after resetting the phone - that the user apps get deleted, the phone won't start as it's missing the app).

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219561

Comment: this app can disable recovery (and even download mode) but it's a paid solution for companies only https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manageengine.mdm.android ([source](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=76394244&postcount=13))

Comment: @alecxs I don't think it'd be possible - at least on every device - to disable recovery mode by enforcing work profile policy.

Answer (score 1):

OrangeFox Recovery allows option to lock Recovery with a Pattern or PIN 
It will prevent normal youtube users from reseting your phone
but their is a catch people with deep knowledge will flash
Fastboot ROM or Qfil ROM and make device useable again but all data will be lost  .

Best option is to use Phones in which bootloader unlock is not possible because of missing adb and fastboot devices like Honor

Regardless of what you do with some difficulty it is possible to fACTORY reset with proper tools by Government Agencies and then recover deleted data.